# Use fgetcsv() to import each row into different tables in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How can I use fgetcsv() to load or import each row of a csv into different tables in mysql php or is there a better way than using fgetcsv() ?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the many duplicates for fgetcsv : [Writing a PHP file to read from CSV and execute SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937912/writing-a-php-file-to-read-from-csv-and-execute-sql-query)