# SQL Select statement on cvs file in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to do some sql querying on cvs file in php. I found this

[Writing a PHP file to read from CSV and execute SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937912/writing-a-php-file-to-read-from-csv-and-execute-sql-query)

but I was unable to change it for the SELECT statement

my attempt:

```
<?php
$fin = fopen('./file.csv','r') or die('cant open file');
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'name', 'pw');
If (!$conn) {
    die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
@mysql_select_db('name') or die ('Unable to select database');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conn);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $conn);

echo "Connection succeeded <br />\n";

while (($data=fgetcsv($fin,1000,","))!==FALSE) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM file";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
      print_r($row);
    }

    }
fclose($fin);
mysql_close();
?>
```

lets say I have an *file.csv* and I want to execute something like this: `Select col1,col2 from file.cv where c3='whatever'`

OR is there some other, more elegant way how to querying cvs in php?

Thank you!

Comment: any reason not to read it in to a db table?

Comment: editing csv on the spot is much more convenient for me.

Comment: the query is just select every thing -im really confused what you actually want

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: I want to do an regular sql select statement on cvs file in php, like: Select col1,col2 from file.cv where c3='whatever'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query a CSV file with SQL style queries. There are some command line tools available that you might be able to wrap with PHP, but you cannot do it directly.

Comment: so sql in php can do Update statement on cvs file but can not do select statement on it?

Comment: You cannot do any SQL functions on a CSV file without a plugin or command-line widget of some sort.

Comment: but this thread says that you actually can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937912/writing-a-php-file-to-read-from-csv-and-execute-sql-query

Comment: They're not updating the CSV, they are reading from a CSV and using the data in the CSV to update a MySQL database.

Comment: well, ok then, I will do it with the fgetcsv, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

as said, not possible. Instead read csv contents into an array and iterate over the array.